# Entering Romania on a Bulgarian visa

Tags: visas, public-transport, romania

I am an Egyptian travelling to Bulgaria. I only have a Bulgarian visa. Can I fly to Bucharest (Romania) for 2 days with my Bulgarian visa and then travel to Bulgaria?

If it's possible, will I have any problem at the airport here in egypt or in Bucharest? I will have a hotel reservation and a Bulgarian ticket.

Comment: Do you have a multiple entry schengen visa issued by Bulgaria or a long-stay/resident visa? See [this page](http://cairo.mae.ro/en/node/836) from the Romanian embassy in Cairo.

Comment: @mkennedy both bulgaria and romania aren't shengen

Comment: Then if I'm interpreting the linked page correctly, you would need a resident/long-stay Bulgarian visa or a multi-entry Schengen visa from another country to not have to apply for a Romanian visa.

Comment: @mkennedy my bulgarian visa for 44 days , can u check that and tell me what u understand please ?? http://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040 !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page http://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040 lists among people who do *not* need a Romanian visa:

> The holders of visas [...] issued by Bulgaria [...].

So having a Bulgarian visa will exempt you from needing a separate Romanian visa *as long as* you still have at least one entry and sufficient duration-of-stay left on the Bulgarian visa:

> **Attention!** The number of entries as well as the right of stay established as per such visas must not have been exhausted. The right of stay on the territory of Romania shall not exceed the right of stay granted as per such visas/residence permits.

There is more information, including a reference to relevant EU legislation, at http://www.mae.ro/en/node/30330.

Comment: thank you , but my visa to bulgaria just single entery , but hasn't used yet this my first time travelling , at the first i want to go to bucharest for 3 days and then travelling to bulgaria from bucharest , will that be allowed with that single entry ?

Comment: @megomegz: The rule does not seem to apply to single-entry visas. It doesn't say so very explicitly, though, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: u mean that he count only for bulgaria , if i travelled first to bucharest and then from bucharest to sofia with my single entry visa will be no problem ??

Comment: @megomegz: No, I mean that what I wrote: **the rule does NOT seem to apply to single-entry visas**. What about that is hard to understand?

Answer (score -1):

You can't enter in Romania if you don't have a Romanian visa, even if you have a Bulgarian one that doesn't help you. On the official site http://www.mae.ro/node/1469 you can find all the answers.