# Changing from single entry to multiple entry visa

Tags: visas, multiple-entry, bulgaria

I have a single-entry visa for Bulgaria. It would start tomorrow but I didn't use it yet and I want to go and stay a day in Bucharest from Sofia and come back to Sofia.

I think because my visa is single-entry they won't allow for me to enter again, can I go to embassy and ask them to make my visa multiple entries before travelling? Or is there another solution like get a permission from Bulgaria or something like that?

Comment: Duplicate? http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51618/entering-romania-on-a-bulgarian-visa

Comment: @mkennedy the linked question does not explicitly concern a single-entry visa.

Comment: @phoog Based on a comment in the accepted answer, yes, it does.

Comment: @mkennedy did u read the question ?? , i ask if i can ask the embassy to change entries state from single to multiple before travelling or not !!

Comment: @HeshamAbusaif I think the answer is yes, you can ask.  I do not know whether they will entertain your question, or how likely they are to look upon it favorably, but you can certainly ask.  If you have a good and convincing reason to travel to Romania, they may grant your request.  I suspect they'll tell you to make a new application for a dual-entry visa, however.  The only way to find out for sure is to call the embassy and ask.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you don't meet the conditions for a multile entry visa. From the [Bulgarian Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mfa.bg/uploads/files/VISA_C_en.pdf)

> A  multiple visa with a validity term of up to  one  year may
>   be  issued to a foreigner provided he/she has obtained a short-stay
>   visa in the preceding year and it was used in compliance with the
>   legal provisions for entry and stay in the Republic of Bulgaria and
>   there are grounds to apply for a multiple entry visa.
>
> A  multiple  short
>   - stay  visa  may   be  issued  to  a  foreigner  who  meets  any  of  the  conditions below :
>
> 1. Maintains lasting business contacts with Bulgarian natural or legal persons engaging  in business in the meaning of the Commerce Act;
> 2. maintains  lasting  business  contacts  with  Bulgarian  legal  persons  engaging  in  business in the meaning of the Non - Profit Legal Persons Act;
> 3. maintains  lasting  business  contacts  with  representation  offices  of  foreign  legal  persons registered pursuant to article 24
>      of the Investment Promotion Act;
> 4. has substantial pers onal contribution to the development of bilateral relations with the  Republic of Bulgaria;
> 5. is a member of the family of a Bulgarian citizen in the meaning of the Foreigners in  the Republic of Bulgaria Act;
> 6. is a member of the family of a citizen of a Europe an Union member - state, of the  European Economic Area or of the Swiss Confederation residing permanently in the  Republic of Bulgaria;
> 7. is  a  member of  the family  of a foreigner  residing permanently  in  the  Republic of  Bulgaria keeping his/her customary residence abroad;
> 8. is a driver of international road transport or a member of a crew of railway transport  for passengers and goods.