# Entering Bulgaria with multiple entry Romanian tourist visa

Tags: visas, romania, bulgaria, azerbaijani-citizens

I have got Romanian multiple entry tourist visa. My visa starts on 7th of June. I am planning to fly to Turkey and take a bus from Istanbul to Bucharest.

So, can I pass Bulgaria border with my multiple entry Romanian tourist visa?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Entering Romania on a Bulgarian visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51618/entering-romania-on-a-bulgarian-visa)

Comment: That linked question is the opposite situation. In that question OP has a Bulgarian visa, in this question an Romanian visa.

Comment: Fred what is your nationality? It may make no difference but it should always be considered in visa questions.

Comment: Yes, it is opposite situation. My nationality is Azerbaijani

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can enter Bulgaria with your Romanian visa.

Bulgaria allows you to enter without a Bulgarian visa of you are the holder of a visa issued by Romania, Cyprus or any of the Schengen states.

Source: [Bulgarian MFA](https://www.mfa.bg/en/services-travel/consular-services/travel-bulgaria/visa-bulgaria)

Comment: Thank you, 2 question: 1) Should I enter romania first or not? 2) My visa for romania should be started when I enter to bulgaria?

Comment: @Fred1998 As you can read in the documentation I linked to, you do not have to enter Romania before you can use the Romanian visa to enter Bulgaria.

Comment: I just called them and they told me that I should enter romania first. Which is weird

Comment: @Fred1998 I don't have a crystal ball. Who are 'them'?

Comment: I am so sorry, I am a bit nervous right now, because I am running out ot time. I called embassy a week ago, and they told me that If i have multiple entry visa, i can pass bolgaria first. Now they told me that I should enter romania first